# Redirect to another page after PHP script

Tags: php

I want to redirect to a confirmation page after the person has registered, once they have entered the details they need it is sent to the database using the PHP script below which all works. Although when I try to add a redirect using header, it does not run the PHP script. Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['interest'])){

$firstname = ($_POST['firstname']);
$surname = ($_POST['surname']);
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password1 = ($_POST['password']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
$interest = ($_POST['interest']);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (firstname,surname,username,password,email,interestarea,user_type) VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password1','$email','$interest','normal')");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change location?

Comment: I haven't shown my change location code in here as I was hoping someone could add that for me. But when I do the location changes, but the PHP does not run and no data is added to the database

Comment: After the query you need to use header('Location:page.php');

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` libraries as they're deprecated currently and removed in `php >= 5.5.0`. Please consider upgrading to [MySQLI](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and using [MySQLI Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to safeguard yourself from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Note that the location change with `header('Location: ....');` sends a HTTP header, therefore there must not be any other output (from echo or from errors) BEFORE the location change.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yeah, that's exactly the problem. How would I go about this, without removing the ability to run the script first?

Comment: @user3144564 either you catch all the output (using `ob_start()`, see php.net) or you use JavaScript or META redirect in the `<head>` section of the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements as mysql_ functions have been deprecated. You should at least look into using something like mysql_real_escape_string as you may be open to sql injection attacks.

Otherwise, like others have said use:

```
header("Location: new_page.php");
exit();
```

Comment: +1 for `exit`. PHP goes on processing the script without it, and a browser would not have to follow the location header either

Comment: @DanFromGermany +1 As I forgot to give an explanation of using it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `header('Location:yourpage.php');`

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (firstname,surname,username,password,email,interestarea,user_type) VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password1','$email','$interest','normal')");
 header('Location:yourpage.php');
 exit();
```

You can add the `@ob_start();` on top of the page.

Comment: Just a note and a question.. headers start with a capital letter and have a space after the `:`. And the url in it should be url encoded or not? So I suggest `header('Location: your%20page.php');`

Comment: The URL should be URL-encoded. It should (for instance) not be HTML-encoded (because we're not dealing with HTML output here).

Comment: its no matter for location to has a lower case 'l'

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (firstname,surname,username,password,email,interestarea,user_type) VALUES ('$firstname','$surname','$username','$password1','$email','$interest','normal')");

header('Location: page.php');
```

Include at the beginning of the script:

```
<?php 

ob_start();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess on what your problem might be:

You say the page is redirecting, but the php is not parsed. So... if the page just displays your php, it means is outside php reading directory... check that pls (see if it starts with localhost/your ip/domain, etc).